# Events on newly created elements - on() vs live()

Tags: jquery

I have put together the following code as an experiment:

HTML:

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

    $newButton = $('<button />');
    $newButton.addClass('newButton');
    $newButton.attr('href', '#');
    $newButton.html('A New Button');

    $('body').append($newButton);


});
```

The code itself works fine, and as expected when the button is clicked, jQuery produces a new button. The issue thats led to me scratching my head is that the newly created buttons don't react to being clicked, in other words, it won't create a new button, even though the jQuery code targets all  elements.

I understand that live() is no longer supported since 1.7 and has since been replaced with on(). As you can see, the above code uses the on() event however I'm not getting the result that live() use to offer.

Clearly I'm going wrong somewhere, can anyone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `.on()` you need to delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree:

```
$("#someCommonAncestor").on("click", "button", function () {
    // Do stuff
});
```

This is exactly what `.live()` does behind the scenes (it delegates the event handler to the `document`). That's not very efficient, since `document` is as far up the tree as you can go. The closer to the target element you can delegate the event handler the better.

This works because most DOM events bubble up the tree from the element on which they originate (the *target*), through all of the ancestor elements. When the event reaches the element to which you bound the event handler, jQuery checks to see whether the target matches the selector (the 2nd argument to `.on()`) and executes the handler if it does.

Answer (score 1):

The `.on` should be used in a specific syntax to work as delegated events. See below,

```
$(container).on('click', 'child-el-selector', function() {
      //your stuff
});
```

but instead of using delegated events, I would suggest you bind the handler as and when you create the element (direct binding). Like below,

```
function myButtonFx () {
    var $newButton = $('<button />');
    $newButton
        .addClass('newButton')
        .attr({'href': '#'})
        .html('A New Button')
        .on('click', myButtonFx);

    $('body').append($newButton);
}

$('button').on('click', myButtonFx); 
//Note: The above binds only to the button that existed in DOM.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked a treat.